# Solving optimization with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, economics

I am fairly new to Lagrange multipliers. Can someone please show me how to maximize the following function:
\begin{align}
f(x,y)=240\sqrt{x}+y
\end{align}
Subject to:
\begin{align}
30x+y=720
\end{align}

---

Here is what I have done so far, is this on the right track? are there any errors?
\begin{align}
g(x,y,λ)=240\sqrt{x}+y+λ(720-30x+y)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
{\frac{df}{dx}} = 120{x^{-1/2}}+λ=0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
{\frac{df}{dy}} = 2+λ=0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
{\frac{df}{dx}} = 720-30x+y=0
\end{align}
I'm having trouble continuing from here.

Comment: If all you want is a worked example, check Wikipedia or your textbook. If you want *this* problem solved, please [edit] the question to include your own thoughts and efforts, explaining what you've tried and what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Your constraint equation must be set equal to zero (although you will probably find shortcuts to this as you do more problems)...in this case that means $g(x) = 30x + y - 720 = 0$.  Then you set up $h(x, y, \lambda) = f(x, y) - \lambda g(x, y)$.  You then find the gradient of $h$ and set each component to $0$.  This will lead to three equations, with three unknowns: $x$, $y$, and $\lambda$.  The resulting solutions (there very well could be more than one if it's non-linear--which this is) are the possible extrema.  After that, you need to check the boundaries for absolute maxima.

Comment: It might be easier computationally to maximize the square of your function.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. But what does maximize the square mean?

Comment: It means maximizing  $f^2$. But actually don't do this. I first thought the square root was over $x+y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your transposing of the constraint is not right.

$720=30x+y\Rightarrow 720-30x-y=0$. Therefore the lagrange function is

$g(x,y,λ)=240\sqrt{x}+y+λ(720-30x-y)$

Then the **partial** derivatives come next. Pay attention on the corresponding symbols.

${\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}  = 120{x^{-1/2}}-30\lambda=0$

${\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}} = 1-λ=0$

${\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda}} = 720-30x-y=0$

Are the partial derivatives comprehensible ? You have some errors. From the second equation we can conclude that $\lambda=1$. This information can be used to caclulate the value of x. The first equation becomes

$120{x^{-1/2}}-30\cdot 1=0$

$120{x^{-1/2}}=30\quad \quad |\cdot x^{1/2}$

$120=30\cdot x^{1/2}$

$4=x^{1/2}\Rightarrow x^*=16$

The third equation can be used to calculate the optimal value of y.

$720-30\cdot 16-y=0 \Rightarrow 720-480=y\Rightarrow y^*=240$.

Finally you have to calculate $f(x^*,y^*)$.

Comment: The last derivative you wrote should be ${\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda}} = 720-30x-y=0$ and not ${\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} = 720-30x-y=0$

Comment: I can see now where I have made the errors. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for the information. I´ve corrected it.

Comment: @sam You´re welcome.

Comment: It's worth noting that you should, at some point, actually prove this _is_ a maximum and not a minimum.  If the question had been restated as "find the minimum..." then the answer would have been there is no minimum (the function isn't bounded from below).